# Combine v-bind=$attrs with custom attributes in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Is it possible to combine `$attrs` with custom attributes in Vue3 without losing the ability to use event listeners?

Let's say I have an `<input>` element in a `<div>`:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-bind="inputAttributes">
    </div>
</template>


<script lang="ts" setup>

// ...

const inputAttributes = computed(() => {
    return {
        'aria-required': props.required,
        'aria-invalid': !!props.errorMessage,
    }
})
</script>
```

I would like to bind the `$attrs` to the input element & include the aria attributes as well. I tried unpacking the `$attrs` object in the computed `inputAttributes`, however, event listeners on the component stopped working in this case.
I'd prefer not to have to write the attributes to the template. *(because I want to add the same attributes to multiple elements and don't want to repeat them pointlessly)*

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html), the attributes can be used in script block:

> If you do not want a component to automatically inherit attributes, you can set inheritAttrs: false in the component's options.

> If needed, you can access a component's fallthrough attributes in
>
> using the useAttrs() API

> If not using , attrs will be exposed as a property of
> the setup() context

> Note that although the attrs object here always reflects the latest
> fallthrough attributes, it isn't reactive (for performance reasons).
> You cannot use watchers to observe its changes. If you need
> reactivity, use a prop. Alternatively, you can use onUpdated() to
> perform side effects with the latest attrs on each update.

So it's supposed to be:

```
  inheritAttrs: false,
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const attrs = ref(ctx.attrs);

    onUpdated(() => {
      attrs.value = ctx.attrs;
    });

    const inputAttributes = computed(() => ({
      ...attrs.value,
      'aria-required': props.required,
      'aria-invalid': !!props.errorMessage,
    }));

    ...
```

This cannot be achieved with `script setup` because macros like `useAttrs` cover only the common cases.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance), you'll need to add the `inheritAttrs` to false in your script setup.

Comment: I know about `inheritAttrs`, that is not what was asking about. The problem is that I want to combine the `$attrs` object with another one, but when I do it with unpacking, it loses event listeners.

Comment: It's an important part but not the whole solution